# How to connect to a remote Redis cluster within another network?

Tags: redis, redis-cluster

Redis cluster is created with internal ip addresses.

```
M: 24ff344338e4abb4f7f2e888ee9d57843fc46e62 10.0.9.19:6379
   slots:5461-10922 (5462 slots) master
   1 additional replica(s)
S: 9aa005c2d914db12a394af0cb8a0d8e218730099 10.0.9.15:6379
   slots: (0 slots) slave
   replicates f67bbf56d98c2bff9eba343356e2b52bd5e59b12
S: aedd33304e59cbe7091fb36befdb230f3956f03e 10.0.9.16:6379
   slots: (0 slots) slave
   replicates 9cd64e70f9fd7fffb44b79186e09e3872ea3ebb4
M: f67bbf56d98c2bff9eba343356e2b52bd5e59b12 10.0.9.20:6379
   slots:10923-16383 (5461 slots) master
   1 additional replica(s)
S: 2af640e7072b255786b47337e7ca171e0506f5f9 10.0.9.14:6379
   slots: (0 slots) slave
   replicates 24ff344338e4abb4f7f2e888ee9d57843fc46e62
M: 9cd64e70f9fd7fffb44b79186e09e3872ea3ebb4 10.0.9.18:6379
   slots:0-5460 (5461 slots) master
   1 additional replica(s)
```

There is only one public ip for external connection, 54.174.xxx.xxx.

After connecting to the cluster, there is problem for redirecting.

```
52.71.xxx.xxx:6379> lrange mylist 0 -1
-> Redirected to slot [5282] located at 10.0.9.18:6379
Could not connect to Redis at 10.0.9.18:6379: Connection timed out
Could not connect to Redis at 10.0.9.18:6379: Connection timed out
(254.54s)
not connected>
```

It look like redis is asking the client to connect to another node for the data. Is it possible to let the current connected node to fetch data on behave? or Any another solution?

As least, I know Cassandra will fetch data from another node to return instead of redirecting.

Comment: Redis requires an app to have direct access to all cluster nodes. Most probably you could try some proxy, but I have no experience with that.